# Passing values from JS to PHP and Echo back HTML

Tags: javascript, php

I am studying a code and need help to learn further.

The JS code below is from a Q/A html form that sends data to server.
It crosschecks answer and on server and scores the user.

I need help writing a PHP code that receives the inputs using GET method and echo "ok" back to the html.

JS:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            if(this.responseText == "ok") {
                                document.getElementById("messagefont").innerHTML = checkans;
                                document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
                                document.getElementById('submit-btn').value = continuebutton;
                                checkans.focus();
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$errors = array ();

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' );
if (isset ($_GET['answer'])) {
    $answer = $_GET["answer"];
}
else {
    array_push ($errors, no);
}
$response = "";
if (sizeof ($errors) > 0) {
    $response = implode (",", $errors);
}
else {
$response = ok;
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I seem not to be getting something right with the PHP, please i need assistance/guide to fix the PHP code rightly.

Comment: *"I seem not to be getting something right"* - This isn't a particularly specific description of the problem.  Now is the time to narrow down what isn't working and practice some basic debugging skills.  What specifically fails?  Have you opened your browser's debugging tools?  Are there any errors at all on the console?  In the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  Does the URL contain the information you expect?  What is the server's response?  Are there any errors in the server's PHP logs?  Can you add additional debugging output to the server-side code to observe client-side?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at "..server...". (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200

Comment: And have you searched that exact error on your favorite search engine?  There are *many* duplicate questions discussing what that error means and how you can address it.  And it has very little to do with the PHP code, certainly nothing to do with the code shown here.  You are encouraged to start researching the error message you're receiving.

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
Thanks @David that solved my problem.